# Where to store global connections with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, firebase

Where to store application wide connections in Ruby on Rails?

I need to read and write some data to firebase, we're currently using [rest-firebase](https://github.com/CodementorIO/rest-firebase) as an adapter and it works great.

Now each time I have to read or write, I create a new connection, was wondering where can I store this as a global:

`firebase = RestFirebase.new(...)`

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an initializer and store the connection in a global constant.

**Inside of config/initializers/firebase.rb**

```
FIREBASE_CONNECTION = RestFirebase.new(...)
```

And that constant will be available pretty much everywhere you want it.